Pyinstaller with custom modules and packages
I'm trying to create .exe for my python projects but pyinstaller is giving no module found error.
Here is how my folder structure looks like.

I want to create executable for Project 1, 2 and 3 which uses utils.py present in Common folder.
In main.py here is the code snippet that I have used to import files from Common module.
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(SCRIPT_DIR))
from Common import utils

I tried to change .spec file as well, but no luck.
a = Analysis(
    ['..\\Project1\\main.py'],
    pathex=['Main Folder Path'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=['Common'],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)


Ran this cmd from Main folder
pyinstaller Project1\main.py --onefile --windowed
Ran this cmd from Project 1 folder
pyinstaller main.py --onefile --windowed
Python==3.11 and PyInstaller==6.4.0
